# How can I get cents from Decimal

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, decimal

So... I have this application that I'm building with C# and ASP.net Core 3.0 and I need the HourlyRate from model to calculate the payment.

But Hourly Rate is not coming with cents, can someone help?

HourlyRate is decimal:

[image: HourlyRate is decimal]

HourlyRate from View:

[image: HourlyRate from View]

HourlyRate model:

[image: HourlyRate model]

How can I get the cents in model?

After a while searching in documentations, posts, reddits haha I found it, in my startup class in Configure method I put this code setting a Number Decimal Separator and Group Separator and now it works!

```
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");
cultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ",";
cultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";

CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
```

Comment: Is the dot (`.`) actually the decimal separator in your culture ? Waht about typing 11,33 ? That said, please include code snippet, not screenshot of your code. It's painful to read if not

Comment: Yes "," is the decimal separator of my culture but if I type "," in the value, I get an asp-validation error saying "The field HourlyRate must be a number". And sorry about the screenshots, thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
String.Format("{0:#.00}", yourvalue);
```

It will convert 1234567.0000 to 1,234,567.00 format.

Comment: it didn't work unfortunately, got the same value without "," or "."

Comment: instead of {0:C} use {0:#.00}

Comment: Code
String.Format("{0:#.00}", model.HourlyRate.ToString());

Input: 11.33

Output: "1133"
Got the same value, I'm having this issue for a while and menn this is hard haha